# Oracle SID in cx_Oracle call

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Trying to program using cx_Oracle but cannot find a good explanation of where to find the SID value that goes in the following code:

```
import cx_Oracle as oracle
conn = oracle.connect("user/pwd@host:port/SID")
```

Is it a field in the tnsnames.ora or a question to the database manager?  Where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SID is a site identifier in oracle. Its kind of like a "database". This method of connection is not using tnsnames.ora. You can find a similar entry in a tnsnames.ora file to find which values to plug in here.

Answer (score 0):

My connection string was

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe
```

"xe" is SID for me. I was using XpressEdition. I found it at multiple places like

1. There was a folder "xe" at the location "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata"
2. It was there at tns listner log [listener.txt] at path "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\\listener\trace"

   TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
   Tue Jan 13 08:46:53 2015
   Dynamic address is already listened on (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mymachinename)(PORT=1521)))
   13-JAN-2015 08:46:53 * service_register * xe * 0

Notice at the last line above "xe" is SID.